# Popup window losing focus

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, popup

I have a print preview button on an asp.net page that opens a new window with a pdf version of what's currently on the screen so the user can print it out.
However, this window loses focus because an iframe on the parent page refreshes itself after the popup page loads. Is there any way to keep the iframe from refreshing or to restore focus to the popup?

Below is the code I'm using to open the new window.

```
Dim url As String = "frmPrintPreview.aspx"
                btnPrintPreview.OnClientClick = "Javascript:window.open('" & url & "','printpreview','height=420,width=550,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');"
```

This is the code for the iframe:

```
<iframe id="FrameLeft" runat="server" name="FrameLeft" scrolling="no" style="border-right: silver 1px inset;
                    border-top: silver 1px inset; z-index: 110; left: 603px; border-left: silver 1px inset;
                    width: 464px; border-bottom: silver 1px inset; position: absolute; top: 32px;
                    height: 675px" visible="false"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim url As String = "frmPrintPreview.aspx"
                btnPrintPreview.OnClientClick = "Javascript:var win = window.open('" & url & "','printpreview','height=420,width=550,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); setTimeout(win.focus, 0);"
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Didn't work. The iframe keeps refreshing and stealing focus back to the parent window.

Comment: It is refreshing only one time or constantly? If second, then you can try to use interval instead of timeout.

Comment: The page is part of an audit tool. The iframe contains an image (a scanned document) and refreshes under these conditions:
-When the page loads
-When the user selects a different document number
-When the print preview button is clicked

This last one is the one I'm trying to prevent.

Comment: Can you provide live example. I am unable to reproduce your problem.